# How to join lines for multiple arrows

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path-effects

I've successfully joined two paths to create two arrows from a single point but when I add a third arrow I get strange behavior and lose a path.  What is the correct workflow?

Two arrows from a single point...
[image]

But three gives me problems...

[image]

Comment: Arrows can only go from one edge of the path to the other, consider making each arrowhead it's own individual path and just placing them along the corners that you want them.

Comment: Thanks @WELZ, not sure I fully understand what that entails.  Could you please describe the steps in your suggested workflow?

Comment: I just added an answer, too much for a comment.

Comment: How do you create the arrow as "it's own shape"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrows can only go from one edge of the path to the other, consider making each arrowhead it's own individual shape and just placing them along the points of the path/stroke where you want them.

If the arrowhead was it's own shape, you can just place it how you'd like along the path (which would just be a standard stroke)

You could also use [this script](http://shspage.com/aijs/en/#dup_at) called **Dup At Selected Anchors** by *Hiroyuki Sato* to place arrowheads on many points.

You only need to make one and then run the script which will copy them on all the points. (You will still need to manually rotate them how you liked).

---

For the arrowhead, there are many options on how to go about creating one, it is a very simple shape, so it shouldn't be that complicated.

Here I made a few samples I created using some shapes (from the polygon tool) and a bit of *Shape Builder Tool* work:

[image: arrowheads]

---

### Clarification:

Simple path, 3 corners and arrowhead I just made:

[image]

Clone arrowhead 3 times and place how I like:

[image]

Now, to merge the shapes, Select the stroke and go to **Object → Expand** and select only Stroke

[image: ExpandPanel]

Select all the shapes (including the arrowheads) and open the *Pathfinder Panel**

**Window → Pathfinder** or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>

Choose the **Unite** option

[image: PathfinderPanel Unite]

It is now all one path

[image: Final Result]

---

<sup>*You can also just group them together for now, so you can more easily make changes, and then at the end, if you need to, unite them with pathfinder.</sup>

Comment: How does one create an arrowhead as it's own individual shape?  And I'd also like to use a drop shadow, so I think I'd need to join the objects at some point, right?

Comment: Yes, you could expand the path and then use pathfinder merge option.

Comment: Ok thanks, but could you outline the actual steps in that process?  I've only used Pathfinder a handful of times and I still don't understand how to "make an arrowhead it's own individual shape"?

Comment: This is awesome but AI is still closing my path when I try to join more than two paths ... I need three and four arrows coming from a single origin point.

Comment: Don't *join* the paths, just make them independent and you can expand them and unite them later on.

Comment: You sir, have resolved my problem!

Comment: @mikeLdub my pleasure!